# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error after adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to get json from a firebase cloud function.

So the json url works on browser and my android app. But when i try it on my javascript code it doesn't show anything.

And gives me an error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In Node JS

this is my code to send response,

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(datacompletearrayPaged));
```

and on client side ,

I use the following code to get json

```
$.get(url, (r) => console.log(r))
```

Comment: the error messages doesn't lie. The server is responding to something without the header at some point in time.

Answer (score -2):

You need to include the `crossDomain: true` property in your request.

You can't provide options to `$.get()`, so you'll need to use `$.ajax()` instead:

```
$.ajax({ url, crossDomain: true }, r => console.log(r));
```

Comment: ... no. If it's a cross-domain request, jquery changes this flag for you.

Comment: read the docs for what `crossDomain` does, it has nothing to do with CORS and is typically completely misunderstood...as in this answer

Comment: And you *can* provide options to `$.get` in more current versions